# The meaning of "competition" in "The Directorate-General for Competition"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "competition" in "[The Directorate-General for Competition (DG COMP) is a Directorate-General of the European Commission, located in Brussels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directorate-General_for_Competition)" mean "commission" in this context? However, I was not able to find that meaning in this [link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/competition). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. As your link states, it's the body responsible for setting and enforcing competition policy, ie ensuring that markets are fair and that companies are not colluding to create cartels or monopolies.

Answer (score 0):

Here, "competition" is in the sense of business market competition, as in this definition from Merriam-Webster:

> **1 :** the act or process of competing : rivalry: such as
> **a :** the effort of two or more parties acting independently to secure the business of a third party by offering the most favorable terms

Based on your question, you may be confused about the structure of the subject noun phrase. The head noun in the subject of your highlighted sentence is "Directorate-General". The phrase "for Competition" modifies it to tell you which "directorate-general we're talking about.